# Prevent a pop up on new pages if the user has already closed it once

Tags: jquery, popup

I'm using some code to display an email capture form:

```
j(window).on('load', function() {
    preloaderFadeOutTime = 500;
    var leadsTime = 5000;

    function hidePreloader() {
      var preloader = $('.spinner-wrapper');
      preloader.fadeOut(preloaderFadeOutTime);
    }

    setTimeout( function() {
      //Email Leads
      $('.wpcf7').addClass('active');
    }, leadsTime);

    hidePreloader();
  });

  //Hide Email Leads form
  document.querySelector('.wpcf7').addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
  }, false );

  $('.wpcf7 .form-close').on('click', function() {
    $('.wpcf7').removeClass('active');
  });
```

If the user either sends the form or they close it, it goes away, but then if they navigate to any other page, after 5 seconds the form appears again. Is there any way to detect if the user has closed or sent this even after reloading a new page, Which reloads the script entirely?

Comment: You could save a [cookie](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) with a boolean inside indicating if you should show the popup again or not.

Comment: I took the cookie approach, thank you.